# How does the Bitcoin Core wallet generate entropy for the HD seed?

Tags: wallet, private-key, bitcoin-core-development, bip32-hd-wallets, random

How does the Bitcoin Core wallet generate entropy for the HD (Hierarchical Deterministic) seed and ultimately the private keys?

This [post](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/83841/how-does-bitcoind-generate-the-private-key) asks a related question but doesn't focus on the entropy part, more the BIP 32/39 part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bitcoin Core wallet requires entropy both for generating HD seeds and for generating nonces (number used once) used in digital signatures (handled by the secp256k1 library).

raw_avocado discussed how the Bitcoin Core wallet generates entropy for a HD seed on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/raw_avocado/status/1445024873382809604?s=20&t=xYNwB8kdqD1EYFuVWSWT8Q). In summary, by mixing entropy from 4 main sources: low level processor instructions, entropy from the OS, dynamic events and static events.

> **(i) Processor instructions**
>
> RDSEED -  access to the built-in True Random Number Generator on the
> processor.
>
> RDRAND  - access to the built-in Pseudo-Random Number generator that
> gets seeded every time it's called with RDSEED
>
> RDTSC - returns the # of CPU cycles since reset
>
> **(ii) OS sources**
>
> Most of the Linux distributions have specific functions that call
> /dev/urandom, like getrandom,  Where this is not the case it's called
> directly.
>
> getentropy used on Open BSD & Mac  sysctl kern.random on Free & Net
> BSD
>
> CryptGenRandom on Windows.
>
> **(iii) Dynamic Events**
>
> Various clocks are called real-time, monotonic, and boot time.
>
> Resource usage is constantly changing and is a great source of
> entropy.
>
> On Windows, getrusage is called, and on Linux pseudofiles from /proc
> are used or sysctl where available.
>
> **(iv) Static Events**
>
> Anything from static details about compiler version to bitcoin client
> version to CPUID, hostname, network interfaces, kernel info,
> filesystem data.
>
> Even though the Events Static & Dynamic are non-cryptographic data,
> they still increase the entropy.
>
> The Dynamic and Static events are mixed in(mostly) by using `<<` Left
> Shift Bits. Because it's a binary operation, every digit is a power of
> 2, so shifting the bit n positions ends up multiplying by `2^n`. This
> adds further confusion when multiple numbers are used at once. The
> most common method used to mix in the entropy is the SHA512(its
> compression function more precisely). SHA512 works effectively as a
> pseudoRNG, as it shows uniformity, meaning each output has the same
> probability of occurring. In some cases, SHA256 is used.
>
> Good hash functions have a strong avalanche effect, meaning that when
> even a single input bit is incremented, each output bit changes with a
> probability of 50%. The bit diffusion is a result of adding, rotating,
> and XORing chunks of the input.
>
> In this mixing situation, the results of the processor pseudoRNG
> RDRAND are XORed 1024 times. (this is used as a fallback from RDSEED -
> the TRNG). Every call should reseed the PRNG differently and XORing is
> a great way to obfuscate things.
>
> Another technique for strengthening the entropy is hashing inputs in a
> loop for an amount of TIME, not just a number of times. The mixing
> techniques are benchmarked and the benchmarks are also mixed in as
> sources of entropy. With each entropy source and each mix the chances
> of an adversary recreating the entropy decrease exponentially. Even if
> a few of the sources are somehow compromised, it will still result in
> a safe key in the end.